# Ubuntu USB drive not booting in UEFI

Tags: ubuntu, uefi

I'm trying to dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with Windows already installed, but I can't get the Ubuntu live USB drive to boot. I set up the drive using Rufus 3.0 on Windows, with the partition scheme set to GPT, the BIOS mode to UEFI (non-CSM), and the file system set to FAT32. I've also disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot and set the boot order so that USB drives boot first. When I boot from my USB drive, the "Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu" GRUB menu appears, but when I choose one of the options, I just get a black screen. What have I done wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I tried booting from my USB drive on a different machine and it worked just fine. After selecting "Try Ubuntu without installing" from GRUB, I was met with a black screen for only a couple seconds before Ubuntu loaded. The machine that loaded Ubuntu is an Alienware 13 R2 and the machine that won't load it is an Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 14. Both machines are set up the same in UEFI. The only thing I can come up with is that since the Acer has an Intel Celeron N3050, it's too slow to load Ubuntu in a timely manner.

Comment: Use this https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: I tried YUMI, but the laptop didn't even recognize my flash drive as a bootable device. I checked Disk Management in Windows and the partition was set to Active, so it should have been bootable.